# Ubuntu 20.04: su command bash-autocomplete stopped working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, su, bashrc

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. The `su` autocomplete stopped working. For example when  I type:

```
su TabTab
```

It lists the files and directories of the current directory, where as it should list the available users.

Bash auto-complete for other commands is working fine for example:

```
apt-get TabTab
```

It lists the available `apt-get` options.

```
usermod TabTab
```

It lists the available user accounts.

`su` was working fine before and now it is not. I have no idea when it stopped working.

I have checked other questions but most of them are related to **bash-completion**, not specific to `su`. So, before marking it duplicate please check the existing answer if it addresses `su`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution.

It is not an issue but due to the changes in the implementation of **su** command on Ubuntu-20.04.

Here is the workaround:

Edit the following file:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/su
```

Replace line 44:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- $cur) )
```

with

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -u -- $cur) )
```

Source-1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417028/8388883

Source-2: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/253#issuecomment-440591431

The sources are for CentOS, but also working for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with `sudo apt-get install bash-completion -y` and then `source ~/.bashrc`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133086/bash-tab-auto-complete-not-working-for-apt

Answer (score 0):

In 20.04, you can use the following commands by default to make use of autocomplete:

```
sudo -u TabTab
```

```
su - TabTab
```